# How to use SignalR with ASP.NET 5

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core

I've heard recently about SignalR and i want to implement it in ASP vNext .

I've tried some guides for ASP MVC 5 but I couldn't get it working . Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MusicStore sample uses SignalR, please take a look [here](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/master/src/MusicStore).

Let us know if there is something that you cannot figure out

Comment: I see references to SignalR but I see no examples in this project where it is actually using SignalR to send messages via an open connection.

Comment: @Victor Hurdugaci - in the project.json file there is a reference to "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-beta7" which I can't find!  I have all my refs to beta7 but the signalR's only option is the beta5?  Do you know where I can reference the correct version?

Comment: @Victor Hurdugaci - this is the link relating to the above...     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150312/cant-find-microsoft-aspnet-signalr-server-3-0-0-beta7

Comment: The sample you linked doesn't use SignalR (at least now today), is there a different example?

Comment: Link is dead (February 2021).