# Can't find Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server 3.0.0-beta7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am having trouble referencing package:  "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-beta**7**" - the only one I can install is the 'beta**5**' version..

I have seen other examples online where people **do** reference this 'beta7' package but I can't seem to find it?!

Below an image of my current project.json - any help is much appreciated..

[image]

Comment: I've the same problem... take a look [here](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/issues/119)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the aspnetmaster feed to your Nuget sources.

The source is  https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json

Either add it to your NuGet.config file (per-solution nuget source) like this:

```
<add key="aspnetmaster" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json" />
```

Alternatively, add it to your global sources in Visual Studio options.

Comment: Thanks for that - in the end I reverted back to beta5 which works ok - but I had a look and indeed that is where the beta7 is hiding (include prereleases) and it appears in the list!

Comment: Great to hear it worked. I am using the beta8 version and it works fine.