# SignalR not working in ASP .Net 5 RC-1

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core

I can't seem to get SignalR 3 working on ASP .Net 5 RC-1 upgrading from Beta8. I tried the latest RC1 package for SignalR but had the following problem. I tried the `"Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-rc1-15810"` package

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

is causing the following error:

> The type 'IServiceCollection' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

and `app.UseSignalR();`

is causing this one:

> The type 'IApplicationBuilder' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

When I switch to the `"Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-rc2-15909"` package I get a runtime error:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Http.RequestDelegate' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Comment: SignalR is not supported for Asp.Net 5 v1.

Comment: @Tratcher what about [this](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server).  Also it looks like [this](https://github.com/aspnet/BugTracker) is using it.

Comment: @Tratcher it definitely is supported. The answers below worked for me, and I have been using it with beta 8 for the past few weeks.

Comment: It's there, but it's not supported for v1: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap#future-work

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've just tested this, and it looks like a reference to the [aspnetmaster myget feed](https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json) is required, even though this is not mentioned in the [installation docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html).

Prior to including aspnetmaster I could only resolve `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server 3.0.0-rc1-15810` either directly or by specifying `rc1-*`, which does not build against `rc1-final`.  Including aspnetmaster gives access to `rc1-final`.

If you're using Visual Studio 2015, go to Tools > Options > Nuget Package Manager > Package Sources and add a new feed called whatever you like but with source set to `https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json`.

If you're not using VS2015, or you don't want to edit your machine-wide config, add/edit NuGet.config in your solution root directory to include a package source as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="aspnetmaster" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might have been a package source but couldn't find which one.

Answer (score 5):

Use MyGet sources for "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-rc1-final"

Here related answer, that can be helpful: 
[Can't find Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server 3.0.0-beta7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150312/cant-find-microsoft-aspnet-signalr-server-3-0-0-beta7)

Comment: can you please elaborate here?

Comment: You need to add the aspnetmaster feed to your Nuget sources.


The source is **https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json**
(In Visual Studio click - **Tools => Options => Nuget Package Manager => Package Sources**).


Then you will be able to write and resolve `"Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-rc1-final"`
in your project.json file.

Comment: Here means in your answer, not in comment. Remember it for future.

Comment: Could not install 3.0.0-rc1-final after I add new nuget feed unless I restarted Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking at this page now, the aspnetmaster feed has removed "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-rc1-final"